# What is Elementary OS based on?

Tags: elementary-os

I've seen how Ubuntu is based on Debian, and how Manjaro is based on ArchLinux.

What is [Elementary OS](https://elementary.io/) based from?

May I also ask on how the bases differentiate the OS itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The most easily available resource to find out such things is a site called [Wikipedia](https://wikipedia.org/), accessible with a web browser. There you can find an [article on Elementary OS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_OS) that answers both of your questions:

> Elementary OS (styled "elementary OS") is a Linux distribution based on Ubuntu.

and:

> The Elementary OS project aims to solve a number of perceived deficiencies in the established desktop environments, namely:
>
> - better global aesthetics by streamlining the user interface;
> - reduce software dependency by using core applications written in the C language or Vala;
> - diminish the need to access the terminal.